# Using a PHP multidimensional array as a database

Tags: php, arrays, database, security

I'm building a private CMS for my own use and am at the point where I will start building out the username and password storing features. I am considering the possibility of storing all admin username, password, and user details in a multidimensional array within a PHP file, rather than using SQL to store them in a database.

My reason for wanting to use this non-traditional approach of storing user info is the belief that this will make it harder for attackers to gain unauthorized access to user info (usernames, passwords, IP addresses, etc.), because I will not be connecting to a MySQL database.

**Rough Outline of Code:**

*add_user.php*

```
// set the last referrer session variable to the current page 
$_SESSION['last_referrer'] = 'add_user.php';

// set raw credential variables and salt
$raw_user = $_POST['user'];
$raw_pass = $_POST['pass'];
$raw_IP = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$salt = '&^${QqiO%Ur!W0,.#.*';

// set the username if its clean, else its false
$username = (is_clean($raw_user)) ? $raw_user : false; // is_clean() is a function I will build to check if strings are clean, and can be appended to an array without creating a parsing error.

// set the salted, sanitized, and encrypted password if its clean, else its false
$password = (is_clean($raw_pass)) ? $salt . encrypt($raw_pass) : false; // encrypt() is a function I will build to encrypt passwords in a specific way

// if username and password are both valid and not false
if( $username && $password ) {

    // set the users IP address
    $IP = sanitize($raw_IP);

    // create a temporary key
    $temp_key = $_SESSION['temp_key'] = random_key(); 

    // random_key() is a function I will build to create a key that I will store in a session only long enough to use for adding user info to the database.php file

    // add user details array to main array of all users
    $add_user = append_array_to_file('database.php', array($username, $password, $IP)); 

    // append_array_to_file() is a function I will build to add array's to the existing multidimensional array that holds all user credentials. 

    // The function will load the database.php file using cURL so that database.php can check if the temp_key session is set, the append_array_to_file() function will stop and return false if the database.php file reports back that the temp_key is not set.

    // The function will crawl database.php to read the current array of users into the function, will then add the current user's credentials to the array, then will rewrite the database.php file with the new array. 

    // destroy the temporary session key
    unset($_SESSION['temp_key']);
}
else {
    return false;
}
```

*database.php*

```
$users_credentials = array(1 => array('username' => 'jack', 
                                      'password' => '&^${QqiO%Ur!W0,.#.*HuiUn34D09Qi!d}Yt$s',
                                      'ip'=> '127.0.0.1'), 
                           2 => array('username' => 'chris', 
                                      'password' => '&^${QqiO%Ur!W0,.#.*8YiPosl@87&^4#',
                                      'ip'=> '873.02.34.7')
                          );
```

I would then create custom functions to mimic SQL queries like **SELECT** for use in verifying users trying to log in.

**My Questions**

1. Is this a bad idea, and if so, why?
2. Am I correct in thinking that this will reduce the number of possibilities for hackers trying to gain unauthorized access, sniff/steal passwords, etc., since I'm not connecting to a remote database?

Comment: If using tools such as firebug or something, it could be possible to view the entire array. I would not recommend using this

Comment: @DarylGill if that were true, then wouldn't any and every PHP script be unsafe/vurnerable?

Comment: 1) Yes - it's a lot of work for very little gain, and in fact may result in more risk.  2) Only if you have thought of every vulnerability others have and more.  If you're really worried about traffic sniffing, tunnel your mysql connection over ssh.

Comment: @deraad It is easy enough to open an array to be viewed by development consoles; then you've got to take into account how will you search the multi-dimensional array and return the correct dimension of said array; It is a lot of work, and you are better off thinking up a different method

Comment: @sonofagun Why do you think this approach would yield very little gain? Even using ssh, it seems to me that having any kind of remote connection will always make things more vulnerable. So if there is no remote connection at all, wouldn't that remove an enormous amount of possibilities for attacks?

Comment: With this scheme, all they need to do is read a file and they have hit the jackpot. Really bad idea.

Comment: @rambocoder I think you misunderstood, the array will be stored as an ARRAY in a variable of a PHP file. If you could read the code of a PHP file as plain text as you're suggesting, then you could just as easily read the mySQL connection hostname, username, and password as those are generally stored as variables/constants somewhere in a PHP file.

Comment: But in order to query to mysql database, you need to be able to *execute code* on the server. finding a way to execute code is more difficult than finding a way to read a file that has permissions setup so that the webserver user can read it.

Comment: And, allow me to emphasize that once they can start executing code, the server is generally considered totally compromised.

Comment: @rambocoder That's a good point! Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: **Watch out!**  It looks like you're rolling your own password hashing.  *Don't*.  And definitely don't use the same salt for everyone.

Comment: @Charles yea thats my error with the salts... But why do you think I shouldn't use my own hashing function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any advantage: Whether you use a text file, a mysql database or a php file ( === text file), they are all "databases" in the sense that they are files where you store your information. The difference is that an sql database is made for that stuff;

I do see disadvantages as there are more potential holes you would have to think about. Some examples (apart from the stuff mentioned in the comments):

- You need to take care that the password file is always out of the web-root in case php dies on you;
- You need to avoid passing around your password file in for example source control.

These are not things that are hard to solve, but using a normal database you don't even have to worry about them.

Apart from that are misunderstanding the purpose of the salt: If you just prepend it to the encrypted password, there is really no point in using a salt, you need to send it to your `encrypt` function to hash it with your text-password so that rainbow tables would have to be generated for each password instead of just one for your whole database. And for that reason you should also not use a single salt for all your users, each should have a different, unique salt.

Comment: So would you say that my approach using no remote database connection has makes no difference in terms of increasing security, as opposed to remotely connecting to a mySQL server database?

Comment: @deraad No, I think using proven solutions like mysql in combination with prepared statements, modern hashing algorithms and generally accepted best security practices (the salt for example) will do more for security than a custom db solution could ever do and like I said, a custom solution means you have to account for everything yourself (what if your hashed password contains a backslash or quotes, the above issues, etc.) and I don't see any advantage, even if you get it right.

Answer (score 1):

If you plan to store any kind of config data in a text file of any sort, as opposed to a traditional database, consider using an .ini file. If I'm not mistaken, you can also take advantage of storing it outside of your web root, just like the `php.ini` file.

Here's a great post explaining exactly how to go about this: [Using ini files for PHP application settings](http://brian.moonspot.net/using-ini-files-for-php-application-settings)

[PHP Manual: get_cfg_var()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-cfg-var.php)